# Redirect to dynamic relative paths with .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to make .htaccess "understand" dynamic relative paths and redirect to them properly?

My setup goes as follows:

```
http://domain.com/htroot/aaa/xyz
http://domain.com/htroot/bbb/xyz
http://domain.com/htroot/ccc/xyz
```

And so on. For the sake of the example, "htroot" contains the .htaccess I need to modify. The following sublevels (aaa, bbb, ccc) can be any a-z0-9 name, and the folders have an index.php (or any other .php to be redirected to). The `xyz` should work as a parameter of sorts, see next part. The `xyz` part is nowhere on the filesystem as a "physical" folder or file.

What I need to achieve is the following: When you access with the url

```
http://domain.com/htroot/aaa/xyz
```

it gets content from

```
http://domain.com/htroot/aaa/ (or http://domain.com/htroot/aaa/index.php, either way)
```

where the index.php kicks in -> I can get the `xyz` parsed from REQUEST_URI and process it to serve the correct content that it specifies, while the URL of the page stays as `http://domain.com/htroot/aaa/xyz`, naturally.

So far I have managed to pull this off if every sublevel (aaa etc.) has it's own .htaccess, but I would need one where there is only a single .htaccess located in `htroot` that handles this. I'm guessing it might have something to do with the $0 parameters in .htaccess, but not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to perform something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /htroot/$1/index.php?data=$2 [L]
```

If the first wildcard match `(.*)` is `aaa` and the second wildcard match `(.*)` is `xyz` (htroot/aaa/xyz) it will get the content from

> htroot/**aaa**/index.php?data=**xyz**

and you will be able to get the value **xyz** in index.php with `$_GET['data']`

Comment: if the htaccess is in the root, htroot part of the url will be removed. If the htaccess is inside htroot (like Harri described), you need to remove `htroot/` from the code. I also think this code creates an infinite loop.

Comment: Ah, I missed the loop. Sorry for that! Added the rewrite conds to only perform the rewrite rule, if the file/directory doesn't exist. Using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php$` would be another possibility.

Comment: Glorious. Exactly what I was looking for and works as intended, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

OK, there's something I don't understand in the way it works, I guess I still have a lot to learn about mod_rewrite.

But like this in htroot/.htaccess file, it works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^aaa/(.*)$ aaa/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^bbb/(.*)$ bbb/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ccc/(.*)$ ccc/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

You will be able to access $_GET['xyz'] or whatever you put after / in your index.php scripts. You will also get a bonus 'index_php' entry in the $_GET array, but I guess it's the way the internal redirect works.

Comment: Works to some extent, but isn't dynamic I'm afraid. I could have a few or a hundred aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd etc. folders, so would need to be kept in sync with the folders always.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as a generic ruleset:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) /htroot/$1/index.php?parameters=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Same idea as the above one. Works well too!