# Dynamik redirect with htaccess and path structure

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to setup an htaccess redirect rule which redirects the following pattern:

```
https://www.example.com/something/ABC123455
```

to

```
https://www.new-domain.com/something/ABC123455
```

while `ABC123455` is a dynamic string which can include any upper cased letter and number with exactly 8 characters.

So I guess the regex for this would be:

`([A-Z0-9]){8}`

So I am looking into several guides:
[Redirect to dynamic relative paths with .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591100/redirect-to-dynamic-relative-paths-with-htaccess)
https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/htaccess-redirect-with-dynamic-strings/74591

but all I learn is how to setup a route redirect via query parameter `?var=ABC` and so on.
Can someone bring me to the right track here? It can't be that hard.

Comment: Well put the back reference to your captured match into the path, and not the query string, of the replacement URL then …? Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this rule in site root .htaccess of old site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^something/[A-Z\d]{8}/?$ https://www.new-domain.com/$0 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Strangely this redirects straight to `www.new-domain.com` when entering `www.example.com/something/ABCD1234` in the browser so it does not seem to respect the part after the TLD

Comment: Same issue. The URL I get is the correct one but its redirecting to the false one. Good hint with the cache disable option though as I was struggling to properly test this before.

Comment: Its also not working with any other 301 disabled, leaving this the only rule in the file.

Comment: One question: Why would the `RewriteCond` be needed here if the TLD is already exactly this domain?

Comment: I now tried to make the rule a bit more open which worked fine for me:
`RewriteRule ^something/(.*)$ https://www.new-domain.com/something/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: So sorry, I realize my mistake now. It should be `$0` not `$1`. Please try my updated rule now. `RewriteCond` is needed in case both old and new domains point to same host and directory to avoid a redirect loop.